# Padding is breaking my responsive 2 col layout that needs to stack when scaled to mobile

Tags: html, css, flexbox, responsive-design

```css
body {
  font-family: Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "sans-serif";
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.videowrapper {
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 56.25%;
  padding-top: 25px;
  height: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
}

iframe {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.flex-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.leftcontent {
  background: #074987;
  width: 47.9%;
  float: left;
  padding: 20px
}

.rightcontent {
  background: #FF3701;
  width: 47.89%;
  float: left;
  padding: 20px;
}

.blocktitle {
  color: white;
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 54pt;
}

.blocktext {
  color: white;
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 14pt;
}


/* Use a media query to add a break point at 800px: */

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .leftcontent,
  .rightcontent {
    width: 100%;
    /* The width is 100%, when the viewport is 800px or smaller */
  }
}
```

```html
<section class="video-container">
  <div class="videowrapper">
    <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/uJU58VAJDpE" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen>
            </iframe>
  </div>
</section>
<section class="container">
  <container class="flex-wrapper">
    <div class="leftcontent">
      <div class="blocktitle">
        Who We Are
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="rightcontent">
      <div class="blocktext">
        Family, service, community and friendship. These are words that are rarely used to describe today’s “Big Box” retail outlets. Somewhere far away from here, it was decided that shopping for building materials meant wandering through an enormous warehouse
        with little to no direction. This meant receiving minimal support from the clerks, loading your own lumber, and seeing no friendly and familiar faces. Our response to that is simple – “That’s not the way we do business.”
      </div>
    </div>
  </container>
</section>
```

I tried entering padding to all parent blocks (.leftcontent & .rightcontent) and children block (.blocktitle & .blocktext) but the results were either the layout wrapping on desktop breakpoint (I only want the wrapping for mobile size) or and overflow that made the screen scroll left and right. I am still learning HMTL and CSS so maybe my use of the flex box layout could be optimized or correct to fix this issue im not sure.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please 1) edit your post to convert it into a runnable "code snippet"  2) keep only what is absolutely necessary to make it understandable. Currently the code is too long.

Comment: @Basj how can I convert. Sorry im at working doing multiple things and very new to SO. Thank you for you help and input!

Comment: There is "Edit" button on your post. Then there is a "Snippet" button in the toolbar when you edit your post.

Comment: @Basj Okay. I believe I was able to convert to code snippet. Can you confirm?

Comment: Well done @Joneaux318!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue here is that you are mixing flexbox and float styles which shouldn't go together on the same sections of a webpage. I have fixed your layout by removing the `<container></container>` element and by removing the float rules, thus only working with flexbox.

```css
.leftcontent {
  background: #074987;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```css
.rightcontent {
  background: #FF3701;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

Those two changes alone (removing the container div and editing the two rules) should fix the desktop viewport.

In order to make also the mobile viewport work you should change the media query to this:

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .leftcontent,
  .rightcontent {
    width: auto;
  }
  .container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}
```

With flexbox you just change the direction from row to column and the mobile part should be working. I don't know exactly why the 100% part is not working, but using `width: auto;` is fine.

**Final point:** media queries are easier to manage in a mobile-first approach, which consists in writing the rules that should apply for every viewport outside of media queries, and specifying only the rules that apply to wider viewports.

In your case the relevant parts would become:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.leftcontent {
  background: #074987;
  padding: 20px;
}

.rightcontent {
  background: #FF3701;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

for mobile, plus

```css
@media screen and (min-width: 801px) {
  .leftcontent,
  .rightcontent {
    width: 50%;
  }
  .container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
  }
}
```

for wider screens.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH!!! That makes lotta of sense!